# column with empty datapoints

Tags: gnuplot, average, stock

```
date  daily  weekly  monthly
1      11             88
2      12
3      45    44
4      54
5      45
6      45    66
7      77
8      78
9      71    99       88
```

For empty data points in weekly column , the plot is ploting values from monthly column.
Monthly column plot and daily column plot are perfect.
suggest something more than  set datafile missing ' ' and set datafile separator "\t"

Answer (score 4):

Alas, Gnuplot doesn't support field based data files, the only current solution is is to preprocess the file. `awk` is well suited for the task (note if the file contains hard tabs you need to adjust `FIELDWIDTHS`):

```
awk '$3 ~ /^ *$/ { $3 = "?" } $4 ~ /^ *$/ { $4 = "?" } 1' FIELDWIDTHS='6 7 8 7' infile > outfile
```

This replaces empty fields (`/^ *$/`) in column 3 and 4 with question marks, which means undefined to Gnuplot. The `1` at the end of the awk script invokes the default rule: `{ print $0 }`.

If you send awk's output to `outfile`, you can for example now plot the file like this:

```
set key autotitle columnhead out 
set style data linespoint 
plot 'outfile' using 1:2, '' using 1:3, '' using 1:4
```

[image: Plot of all columns]

Comment: Nice answer I didn't know that you can use the column head of a file to make auto label titles

Comment: if I need to plot only weekly column wrt date, can you suggest any solution in gnuplot script file.

Comment: @deepak.yadav: Use the same answer, change the plot line to: `plot 'outfile' using 1:3`.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone runs into this, I recommend updating to at least the 4.6.5 Gnuplot version.

This is because from Gnuplot 4.6.4 update:
* CHANGE treat empty fields in a csv file as "missing" rather than "bad"

And there seemed to be a (related?) bugfix in 4.6.5:
* FIX empty first field in a tab-separated-values file was incorrectly ignored

Comment: Good catch. I can confirm, that since 4.6.4 the following commands work fine with the given data set (separated by tabs!): `set datafile separator '\t'; set style data lines; plot 'data.csv' u 1:2, '' u 1:3, '' u 1:4`.