# In a Bar chart, How to put vertical text in place of some of the bars?

Tags: gnuplot

In Gnuplot, I am using a bar chart, but not all data points have values. In those places, I want to replace the bar with a vertical text saying "Cannot Serve". How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have labels to denote missing data, for instance the following data file where missing data are signaled by "NaN":

```
0 2.3
1 3.1
2 NaN
3 6.1
4 0.5
5 NaN
6 NaN
7 4.9
8 7.0
9 NaN
```

you can do conditional plotting such that when gnuplot encounters "NaN" it prints a "Missing data" message:

```
set style fill solid
set boxwidth 0.9
set xrange [-1:10]
plot "data" u ($1):($2) with boxes not, \
"" u ($1):(stringcolumn(2) eq "NaN" ? 1. : 1/0):("Missing data") \
w labels rotate by 90 not
```

[image]

Note that I centered the "Missing data" labels at y = 1. You'll need to adapt that to your needs.

If, instead, your data is just missing:

```
0 2.3
1 3.1
2    
3 6.1
4 0.5
5  
6  
7 4.9
8 7.0
9
```

then things become a bit more complicated, see e.g. [column with empty datapoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317380/column-with-empty-datapoints).

Comment: Asked a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845229/in-a-histogram-chartclustered-how-to-put-vertical-text-in-place-of-some-of-th